# How can I make a graphic with grouped values, stacked and labeled individually and in groups?

Tags: gnuplot

I would like to make a graphic like this, but I can not find similar information.

I have searched for examples on the internet, but the most I find are stacked graphs

!https://www.intechopen.com/media/chapter/54498/media/F1.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing is that you have the data in some useful format.
Since it will be probably an extra effort for gnuplot to group the values into your material categories (but can also be done), it is easier if you give numbers to each of your material categories. Then just plot points and labels. Do not hesitate to post the data and show your code how far you actually got.

**Code:**

```
### plot with labels
reset session

$Data <<EOD
Pt             Metal             1  1750
Graphite       Metal             1  3600
B_4C           Carbide           2  2450
HfC            Carbide           2  3800
Si_3N_4        Nitride           3  1900
HfN            Nitride           3  3300
W_2B_5         Boride            4  2250
HfB_2          Boride            4  3400
Y_3Al_5O_{12}  Oxide             5  1950
ThO_2          Oxide             5  3050
TiSi_2         Intermet.         6  1550
Zr_5Si_3       Intermet.         6  2250
Ti_3SiC_2      "Ternary\nComp."  7  1400
(Hf,Ta)C       "Ternary\nComp."  7  3600
EOD

set bmargin 3
set xrange[0.5:8]
set ylabel "Melting temperatures (°C)
set yrange[1000:4500]
set grid xtics, ytics

plot $Data u 3:4:xtic(2) w p pt 7 notitle,\
     '' u 3:4:1 w labels left offset 1,0 notitle
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: thank you very much for your help.
one more question. How can I change the color of the point to black?
I will continue to complete

Comment: you do `plot $Data u 3:4:xtic(2) w p pt 7 lc rgb "black" notitle ...`, see `help linecolor`. The values for the temperatures are just very rough values which I took from the plot you linked to.